# Trying to validate a json with its json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to write a json schema for my json string, but it keeps on passing an unwanted json format.

The json format I am trying to validate (an array of json objects).

```
  [
    {
      "visitid":1326,
      "Medicines":"some string value",
      "Investigations":"some string value or null value",
      "Procedure":"some string value or null value",
      "advice":"some string value or null value"},
    {
      "visitid":12345,
      "Medicines":"some string value or null value",
      "Investigations":"some string value or null value",
      "Procedure":"some string value or null value",
      "advice":"some string value or null value"
    }
  ]
```

With the following json schema

```
  {
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title":"max-post-request",
    "type":"array",
    "items":{
      "properties":{
         "visitid":{
            "type":"number"
         },
         "Medicines":{
            "anyOf":[
               {
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "type":"null"
               }
            ]
         },
         "Investigations":{
            "anyOf":[
               {
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "type":"null"
               }
            ]
         },
         "advice":{
            "anyOf":[
               {
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "type":"null"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "required":[
         "visitid"
      ]
    }
  }
```

It is working for my json mentioned above but in addion to that it jeeps on passing the following json format as well, which I do not want.

```
  [
    "visitid",
    6197911,
    6276648,
    "Medicines",
    "Some value"
  ]
```

How do I make sure It just passes array of valid json objects, Please help!

Answer (score 1):

you want a `type` constraint on the items of the array. add `"type": "object"` below `items` to ensure each item is an object.

Comment: To clarify, `type` should be added alongside `properties` _inside_ `items`.